# How do you keep a horizontal nav list item that increeses in sized when hovered centered on it's pre-hover location?

Tags: html, css, hover, nav

When hovering on a nav list item (arranged horizontally) that gets larger and gets a margin to create a gap between it and the other list items adjacent to it how do you make it that the hovered item stays centered to its pre-hover location while the adjacent items spread away, to the left and right? Below is the code I have so far (you can also check it out on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/tjfwalker/pen/ewyxE)).

Thanks,
TJ

```
#nav {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        right: 15%;
        font-weight: bold;
        }

        #nav:hover {
            }

        #nav li {
            float: left;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            text-align: center;
            }

            li:first-child {
                border-top: 4px solid white;
                border-right: 2px solid white;
                border-bottom: 4px solid white;
                border-left: 4px solid white;
                }

            li:nth-child(2) {
                border-top: 4px solid white;
                border-right: 2px solid white;
                border-bottom: 4px solid white;
                border-left: 2px solid white;
                }

            li:nth-child(3) {
                border-top: 4px solid white;
                border-right: 2px solid white;
                border-bottom: 4px solid white;
                border-left: 2px solid white;
                }

            li:nth-child(4) {
                border-top: 4px solid white;
                border-right: 4px solid white;
                border-bottom: 4px solid white;
                border-left: 2px solid white;
                }

        #nav li:hover {
            box-shadow:
                2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
                -2px -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
                -2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
                2px -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 5;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            font-size: 1.2em;
            margin: 0 10px;
            }
```

Comment: You are going to need javascript to do this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it using only CSS. So the key is to use:

```
display: inline;
```

on the li, and to wrap the ul in a div that will allow you to:

```
text-align: center;
```

Now that it is centered it will grow from the center. I made the changes here - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uIdsr

Comment: Thanks, man. I like the pure CSS answer. It's funny 'cause I briefly explored the
    display: inline;
idea but didn't think to use an outside div and center within so I didn't think it was the way to go. One issue that still remains, though, with
    display: inline;
is the space that it adds between the line items when they aren't being hovered. I can't figure out how to remove it.

Thanks

Comment: Done. Any thoughts on that space between the line items?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look into it fully but a -4px margin on the li would be quick fix. Will take a look tomorrow and let you know if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Took a bit of manipulating, but here's the code that will do this for you: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cIEno. Please note, this requires jQuery, as you need to move the other elements to keep the hovered one centered.

Comment: Thanks for this. Though I know nothing of js your fixed did a great job.